# Database design, many different items in different columns (item a can be in column a or b)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

So, I have a headache because of designing my database. I have list of drinks with their ingredients, i.e.:

```
name:Tea
ingredient1:teabag
ingredient2:water

name:Glass of water
ingredient1:water

name:Frozen Tea
ingredient1:ice
ingredient2:teabag
ingredient3:water
```

So, as You can see, number of columns may be vary, index of each ingredient also. It's only example, database will containt probably about 100-1000 rows. Could You help me telling the best (or just a good) way to design my database? I have to be able to select based on some or every ingredient, so select where ingredient=water gives 3 results (but in this case I have to send query three times). I have really no idea how to make it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database design where you use columns for the ingredients is called non-normalized. Non-normalized database structures should usually be avoided as they are difficult to maintain and to work with.

See: [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Instead use two tables: One "Drink" table and one "Ingredient" table.

```
CREATE TABLE Drink (
    DrinkID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (DrinkID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE Ingredient (
    IngredientID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    DrinkID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IngredientID),
    INDEX IX_DrinkID (DrinkID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DrinkID) 
        REFERENCES Drink(DrinkID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now you insert records like this:

```
INSERT INTO Drink (Name) VALUES ('Tea');
INSERT INTO Drink (Name) VALUES ('Glass of water');
INSERT INTO Drink (Name) VALUES ('Frozen Tea');
```

Assuming that the automatically generated DrinkIDs are 1, 2 and 3

```
INSERT INTO Ingredient (DrinkID, Name) VALUES (1, 'teabag');
INSERT INTO Ingredient (DrinkID, Name) VALUES (1, 'water');

INSERT INTO Ingredient (DrinkID, Name) VALUES (2, 'water');

INSERT INTO Ingredient (DrinkID, Name) VALUES (3, 'ice');
INSERT INTO Ingredient (DrinkID, Name) VALUES (3, 'teabag');
INSERT INTO Ingredient (DrinkID, Name) VALUES (3, 'water');
```

You can return a list of drinks containing water together with their ingredients like this

```
SELECT
    d.Name AS drink_name, i.Name AS ingredient_name
FROM
    Drink d
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i
        ON d.DrinkID = i.DrinkID
WHERE
    i.Name = 'water'
ORDER BY
    d.Name, i.Name
```

Or, if you want only the drinks as result

```
SELECT
    Name
FROM
    Drink
WHERE
    DrinkID IN (
        SELECT DrinkID
        FROM Ingredient
        WHERE Name = 'water'
    )
ORDER BY
    Name
```

---

You can change the WHERE-clause in the subquery to `WHERE Name IN ('water', 'wodka', 'ice')`. This returns you all the drinks that contain at least one of these ingredients.

If you need to find drinks having all these ingredients you must change the query to

```
SELECT
    d.Name
FROM
    Drink d
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i
        ON d.DrinkID = i.DrinkID
WHERE
    i.Name IN ('water', 'wodka', 'ice')
GROUP BY
    d.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 3
ORDER BY
    d.Name
```

Comment: Ingredients to drinks are many-to-many, though (e.g. "Water" can be in Tea, Water, Frozen Tea), so you should have a junction table.

Comment: @vicvicvic: Yes but only if you want to have a separate table with ingredients, either because you want to able to select from them in a combo box for instance, or if you want to store additional infos, like price or supplier. Here I assume that ingredients are just a text for sake of simplicity.

Comment: I did it like you told. It works! Thanks a lot!! ;) It's exactly what I need.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Hmm, however, I have one last question. If I search using 1 ingredient its simple. But, if I search using 2 or more, it's getting more problematic. It has to search db with 1 ingredient, next with another and in the end with both (because i.e. having water and vodka means I can drink pure water, pure vodka and mixed, as a drink). With 2 ingredients it's still fast, but imagine 10 or more.

Comment: The goal of normalization is to "to minimize redundancy". With two tables, this schema is still just in 2NF and the fact that 'water' is stored three times in ingredient, simply proves it (so as an attribute it depends on drinkid as well and not just on the primary key).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I added column 'Amount' with amount of ingredients to Drink table and I search by i.Name and now d.Amount = x having count(*) = x. It gives me good results, but I have to search y times (y=number of ingredients in i.Name IN (...)), but it's probably ok, so thank you again very much! ;)

Comment: @lp_ You are right, but I'm not using sql for some advanced tasks. I just want to write small app on android using this kind of database (it's very small database). So, for my needs that's ok as far as results are shown in expected time.

Comment: Struggling with data tables data rows and data columns is much more complicated than sending a sql command yielding the final result. Since you added an `sql` tag but no programming language tag, you cannot expect a programmatic solution. If you can, use a simple O/R-mapper, possibly together with LINQ.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yeah, I know and I'm happy about answers I got in here. I did not put any programming language tag because I wanted some knowledge about sql in general. Now everything works fine for me and at least for now quite fast ;) So, thank You again and have a good evening!

Answer (score 3):

I would create three tables:  `Drink`, `Ingredient`, and `DrinkIngredients`.  From there you can insert to the `DrinkIngredients` table as many ingredients as you wish.

Here's an example of this (bear in mind, this is written for SQL Server, as my MySQL knowledge is limited)

```
Create Table Drink
(
    DrinkId     Int             Not Null Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name        Varchar (30)    Null
)

Create Table Ingredient
(
    IngredientId    Int             Not Null Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name            Varchar (30)    Null
)

Create Table DrinkIngredients
(
    DrinkId         Int     Not Null,
    IngredientId    Int     Not Null
)

Alter Table DrinkIngredients Add Constraint FK_DrinkIngredients_DrinkId Foreign Key (DrinkId) References Drink (DrinkId)
Alter Table DrinkIngredients Add Constraint FK_DrinkIngredients_IngredientId Foreign Key (IngredientId) References Ingredient (IngredientId)

Insert Drink (Name) Values ('Tea'), ('Glass of Water'), ('Frozen Tea')
Insert Ingredient (Name) Values ('Ice'), ('Tea bag'), ('Water')

Insert  DrinkIngredients (DrinkId, IngredientId)
Values  (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)


Select  D.Name As Drink, I.Name As Ingredient
From    DrinkIngredients    DI
Join    Drink               D   On  D.DrinkId = DI.DrinkId
Join    Ingredient          I   On  I.IngredientId = DI.IngredientId
Where   D.Name = 'Frozen Tea'
```

You can query the data with the last query to see all of the ingredients for the specified name.  This should give you a decent starting point.

Comment: Should work in MySQL except for `Identity(1,1)` which is `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL.

Comment: I did it in Olivier's way, it was easier for me. But, thanks anyway. To be honest, I didn't expected such fast and great answers :)